# How do you get the last access (and/or write) time of a MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

How do you find out the last time a MySQL database was read or written to?

Can you even do that check per table?

Comment: Almost duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
AND    TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

Source: [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

Comment: It's table_schema, not table_scheme.

Comment: How about the answer for the entire database?

Comment: My DB returns a NULL. Wander why ?

Comment: @adityamenon Leave out the last line and it will give you results for all tables in the database. I did something like this: `SELECT TABLE_NAME, UPDATE_TIME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname' ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME;`

Comment: Note this only stores the timestamp of the last UPDATE. So an INSERT may have been done since, and/or any amount of reads.

Answer (score 4):

If your database has bin logs switched on, you can get the last update time using mysqlbinlog.

If your database has query logging enabled, you can get the last query time (either updates or selects) by tailing the query log.

Answer (score -1):

check out command `SHOW TABLE STATUS`;

example: SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name="table_name_here", you need value from column Update_time