# Go get last access time of a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to know the time when last select statement has been performed on a table? I am using the InnoDB storage engine.

I have tried with the following query:

```
select update_time,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='databasename';
```

..but I'm receiving `NULL` in the `update_time` column.

Comment: select update_time,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='databasename'; but if i try this iam getting null in update_time column

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there, as well as any comment you consider worth adding to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Unless you manually update a `last_accessed`-field on the table, my best bet would be to add query logging and parse the log-files.

I googled and found these relates questions:

[When was the last time a mysql table was accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762539/when-was-the-last-time-a-mysql-table-was-accessed)

[How do you get the last access (and/or write) time of a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344467/how-do-you-get-the-last-access-and-or-write-time-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: I have a query will innodb storage engine stores timestamps of the access time of table?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
AND    TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'`