# Is there a way to find out the last time a mysql database was accessed?

Tags: mysql

I have a virtual hosting, I have simple online browser based ezpanel access. I can manage mysql databases through phpmyadmin.

I have many old databases that I would like to delete. But first, I would need to know, which one are still used by my websites and which are obsolete, unused, unaccessed for many months.

Is it possible to know when the last time a database was accessed?

I am asking, if there's any command that could show if db is being accessed, in use? If there's any info recorded for each db access and any command that shows it? Or any similar method?

Thank you

Comment: Wow, take your pick of the close reasons: Off-topic, not constructive, not a real question, too localized... At least it's not a duplicate. :-) @Neon: Please read the FAQ for why this question isn't for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I'd say it does, yeah. Now it's a http://serverfault.com question, but there's a lot of crossover between serverfault and SO.

Comment: @Neon: You can always edit your question to make it clearer, etc. Don't rely on comments to do that. Use the "edit" link under the question (as Wesley has for you).

Comment: Related: [When was the last time a mysql table was accessed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762539/when-was-the-last-time-a-mysql-table-was-accessed) and [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)... but those are for tables, not entire databases.

Comment: Wesley, excellent, thank you very much. I didn't thought to search for "table" instead of "database". Still very good answers. Thank you and sorry for not searching enough.