# MySQL - Can you query to get last update for a table?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to query a MySQL table and get the last date when anything was done, either insert/update/delete was performed without querying the rows themselves? Or do I have to manually track that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually track that. There are ways to get the query log, but is for administration.

For example, using your innodb binary log.

Comment: Not true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated

Comment: @MattBall You're right. Didn't know that. Anyway, i'd use that inside of a webapp, becouse you would have to allow access to information_schema, and would be a huge security risk. So, rewriting my answer: "for simplicity, you have to manually track that"

Answer (score 0):

that's not something native to MySQL. Your options are either the binary log which only tracks committed changes or by turning on the general log and using that as a point of audit. The general log is extremely vebose - it will log everything, selects, updates, inserts and deletes and even if they're not successful or committed changes. The binary log would be my recommendations too.