# FInd mysql changes in last 24h

Tags: mysql

This post is excellent and shows when last time your table changed 
[How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

but I need to find out the changes and times in last 24h since there was more than one change

Comment: Do you need this on an application level (to show your users "here's what happened in the last 24 hours") or on the management/development level to monitor what is going on in your system?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE UPDATE_TIME >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Or,

```
SELECT *
FROM  information_schema.tables
WHERE UPDATE_TIME >= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: well , maybe i spoke to soon ,, here is the prob.  in mod of the night someone edited my table , this morning i did the change to revert the edits , your query shows only the time i changed it , not the time the guy before me did the change

Comment: second query works also but again , shows only last time any table was changed in 24h, not changes in past 24

Comment: Don't you want to get the changes in last 24 hours?

Comment: I need to get all change times in last 24 , im trying to find who did this and was stupid enough to fast fix the issue without checking last time changed before my fix  , now all i see is time i did the change

Comment: I think, for that you need to create trigger that keep the log of updates in the table....

Comment: @Benn: Take a look at [Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/point-in-time-recovery.html).