# Trigger (AFTER/BEFORE) In Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, insertafter

I have a trigger which is working fine.

```
CREATE TRIGGER crm_listings__au 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON crm_listings FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions 
        SELECT 
            'update', NULL, NOW(), NULL, d.*
        FROM 
            crm_listings AS d 
        WHERE 
            d.id = NEW.id;
```

Now I want to keep track of the field column name also. I am thinking I could not do in above query so I changed to below trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER crm_listings__au 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON crm_listings 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.type != NEW.type
    THEN
        INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions  
            SELECT 
                'update', NULL, NOW(), 'type', d.* 
            FROM 
                crm_listings AS d 
            WHERE 
                d.id = NEW.id;
    END IF;

    IF OLD.price != NEW.price
    THEN
        INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions 
            SELECT  
                'update', NULL, NOW(), 'price', d.* 
            FROM 
                crm_listings AS d
            WHERE 
                d.id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

UPDATE:

I followed this post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563706/is-there-a-mysql-option-feature-to-track-history-of-changes-to-records)

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you changed 4th column from `null` to `'type'` - maybe the 4th column isn't a `varchar` column?

Comment: You forgot to prepend `DELIMITER $$` to the `create trigger` command. Also don't forgot to append `DELIMITER ;` after this command.

Comment: @kordirko: Can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: @radoh:Its string,here is code how i did    ....   ADD action_field VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 'id' AFTER dt_datetime,

Comment: Hm ok, I guess that isn't the problem then. I wonder though - seeing it is defined as `NOT NULL`, how could your previous trigger work, since you were inserting `NULL`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @kordirko: Can you please explain a little bit?

Please study the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program
>   containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. **By default, mysql
>   itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must
>   redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire
>   stored program definition to the server.**
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command. The
>   following example shows how to do this for the dorepeat() procedure
>   just shown. The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire
>   definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then
>   restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ;
>   delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the
>   server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

---

Simple example - I am using MySql Workbench and have copied and pasted your trigger. First some dummy tables:

```
create table crm_listings(
   id int,
   type int,
   price int
);

create table crm_listings_versions(
   ttype varchar(100),
   something varchar(100),
   d date,
   something1 varchar(100),
   id int,
   type int,
   price int
);
```

And now I run your code **without DELIMITER**

```
CREATE TRIGGER crm_listings__au BEFORE UPDATE ON crm_listings 

FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN
    IF OLD.type != NEW.type
    THEN


        INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions SELECT 'update', NULL, NOW(), 'type', d.* FROM crm_listings AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;

    END IF;
    IF OLD.price != NEW.price
    THEN


        INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions SELECT 'update', NULL, NOW(), 'price', d.* FROM crm_listings AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;

    END IF;
END;
$$

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10  0.000 sec
```

**Outcome = Error**

---

Then the same, but with the **DELIMITER** command:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER crm_listings__au BEFORE UPDATE ON crm_listings 

FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN
    IF OLD.type != NEW.type
    THEN


        INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions SELECT 'update', NULL, NOW(), 'type', d.* FROM crm_listings AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;

    END IF;
    IF OLD.price != NEW.price
    THEN


        INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions SELECT 'update', NULL, NOW(), 'price', d.* FROM crm_listings AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;

    END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

0 row(s) affected
```

**Outcome = Success**

Comment: Oh,yes i found like ... delimiter //