# Database metadata table design

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms, database-metadata

I'm working on a **blog** website with an **Admin Panel**. It consists of `Articles`, `Categories`, `Tags`, and `Updates` tables. The `updates` is a `meta-data` table which tracks any updates in any other table. What is the best way to link the `updates` to the others? How can I achieve normalization and avoid redundancy data?
[image]

Comment: Almost by definition, you can't normalize this because the metadata duplicates the info held in "updated_at" in your other tables.

Comment: So, what is the suitable way to make the metadata table to track all the processes, is it ok to remove ```updated_at``` column from all the other tables?

Comment: How do you want to use this information? Normally, you want to keep the attribute (updated_at) with the rest of the information. You could create a view, if you just want to be able to query "most recent changes".

Comment: I want to save every single change _-before & after-_ with the updated table info [**updated_table_name**, **updated_column_name**, **update_itself**, & surely **updated_timestamps**] something like ```commits``` in ```Git``` or so -may be with hash code too-, but I don't know how to link the table ```updates``` to the other tables.

Comment: Is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563706/is-there-a-mysql-option-feature-to-track-history-of-changes-to-records/12564435#12564435