# Why do information_schema.tables convert the UPDATE_TIME values to null after some time?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm fetching `countries`, `cities`, and `frequently_asked_question` from the tables in the server and I store the data locally in the Android app, Look at my scenarios in the Android app:

Old Scenario: When the user opens the app I delete all local data and fetch them again from the server regardless of whether there was any update in the server or the same local data who deleted.

Current Scenario: When the user opens the app I send these variables `countries_update_time`, `cities_update_time`, and `frequently_asked_question_update_time` and compare them inside the PHP file, If the variable who I sent it was the same with the `UPDATE_TIME` in the `information_schema.tables`, I'll return a null value, But if the variable was not the same with the UPDATE_TIME, I'll return the data from the specific table.

Everything is working well but I found a weird problem inside the MySQL database, Look at the image below:

[image]

I'm sure the third table had a date yesterday but today I found the date converted to a null value, Why?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: @Dokik The problem has no any related to code

Comment: `UPDATE_TIME` usage is incorrect itself: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html ***UPDATE_TIME** When the data file was last updated. For some storage engines, this value is NULL. For example, InnoDB stores multiple tables in its system tablespace and the data file timestamp does not apply. Even with file-per-table mode with each InnoDB table in a separate .ibd file, change buffering can delay the write to the data file, so the file modification time is different from the time of the last insert, update, or delete.* `SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM tablename`.

Comment: @Akina `Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.43`. Is this version has any related to my problem?

Comment: *Is this version has any related to my problem?* I doubt. The library can't be imaginative - server tells, library returns.

Comment: @Akina What is the best alternative to apply the current scenario without using `information_schema.tables`?

Comment: ? I have provided the query pattern... does autoutilized `updated_at` column is present in the structure(s)? if not then add... alternatively you may create service table where the datetime for last tables update times should be stored (refresh by triggers).

Comment: I used your query like this `SELECT TABLE_NAME, MAX(UPDATE_TIME) FROM information_schema.tables` Here is the result https://ibb.co/9V2yf8x

Comment: @Akina I forgot to mention you in my previous reply

Comment: ??? you must query your working tables (cities, countries, etc.), not information_schema.

Comment: @Akina But `UPDATE_TIME` exist inside `information_schema.tables`

Comment: *does autoutilized updated_at column is present in the structure(s)? if not then add*

Comment: @Akina This problem will drive me to craziness, I think I'll apply [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563706/is-there-a-mysql-option-feature-to-track-history-of-changes-to-records) instead of the current scenario, Thanks for your time.