# Check if multiple tables were updated

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to do the same thing as in [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated) but for multiple table names.  I can't seem to get it right.  I want to retrieve the update_time for five tables and I assumed I had to do something like

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table2' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table3'
```

but this doesn't seem to work as it just picks up one name all the time.  I'd appreciate any advice you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the difference between the `AND` and `OR` logical operators:

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' OR TABLE_NAME = 'Table2' OR TABLE_NAME = 'Table3'
```