# Node MySQL et Trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js

can we use  triggers in Node.js and MySQL ?
for example I have in my database a table A. And when a user edit a record a message appear :
" the table is modified"

any suggestion !? and thank you

Comment: That's not how triggers work.

Comment: can you explain me how i can do my example ?? thank you.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that that I know of.  Consider changing the processes that write to the DB to push a notification over something like Redis or RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically possible to have a MySQL trigger call a user-defined function (UDF) that can contain a system call using `sys_exec()`, for example. However this solution would be complicated and you would still need to have the client poll the server for changes if you want to display a message in near real-time.

Personally I wouldn't bother with using triggers and just have another process monitor for changes which I would then poll periodically. You could possibly [check the table's last update time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated). The exact implementation would depend on the details of your database structure and how much traffic you need to handle.

Here is a similar question that has more discussion: [Invoking a PHP script from a MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger)