# how to get the last modified time of a particular table mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I want to know the time when my table is last modified ,whether it may insertion,deletion,update or structure change.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query if your db uses the MyISAM storage engine

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

Comment: This is giving me the null..as value in my table

Comment: is your mysql db storage engine  MyISAM or InnoDB ?

Comment: yes UPDATE_TIME works for MyISAM not InnoDB

Comment: Can you try SHOW table status FROM your_database WHERE name = 'your_table';

Comment: both are same SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'

Comment: @GSiry yours will not at all capture the changes for innoDB.