# Backup with mysqldump & rsync

Tags: centos, backup, mysql, rsync

I am trying to backup my database over the network with `mysqldump` and `rsync`.
I wanted to ask if there is any way to know if the database has been modified since the last time I did my old dump, *before* doing a new dump or update the old one.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could dump the database on the local machine, then calculate a checksum over the file. Then you could compare that checksum with a checksum stored on the remove server. If they're different, you copy the new dump to the server and update the checksum.

Comment: rsync already do that,comparing files before making the transfer.so we do not need checksum.

i have a lot of databases to backup and i can't dump each one(huge amount of time) and then rsync it.i want to know before making the dump if it's necessary to do it or not.

thank you

Comment: I see. In that case, I think you'll have to access each database through MySQL and find out when it was last modified. Please see answer below.

Comment: If you compress the files while dumping (nice to save space on disk), consider using `gzip --rsyncable` which compresses while not upsetting rsync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access each database that might need to be dumped and ask for the last modified time. It's available through the `information_schema` database:

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated).

Comment: Thank you for your response.If there's any other method i'am interested.