# Get the list of tables updated in last 24 hours of a database in MySQL with engine myisam or innodb

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

I have tried a `php` script like:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                  FROM  information_schema.'TABLES' 
                  WHERE  UPDATE_TIME > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
                  AND  ABLE_SCHEMA = 'mvgis_lewiscounty'");
```

which is not working.

Can anyone please guide me how should I proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no solution using INFORMATION_SCHEMA that works for both InnoDB and MyISAM.

The `UPDATE_TIME` is not updated for InnoDB tables. Update time for an InnoDB table is kind of subjective. Is it the time someone last did an `UPDATE`? Is it the time that update was `COMMIT`ed? Is it the time the change was flushed to the tablespace?

You'd be better off using a shell command like:

```
$ find /var/lib/mysql -name '*.ibd' -mtime -1
```

Another solution would be for all tables to have a trigger that updates a summary table with one row per table name, to record the latest INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

See also [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated/18369829#18369829)

Comment: I want to keep a check on update. How about MyISAM only? Is there any way where I can get this information without using shell command if I use MyISAM instead?

Comment: Please don't use MyISAM. It's slow, susceptible to corruption easily, and does not support ACID behavior. It's likely to be deprecated in a few years.