# EF and MySQL table last update

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I´m using Entity Framework to pull data from a MySQL database.
I know I can get the last time a given table has been updated.
How can I do this using EF?

Comment: How do you do it in MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Database.SqlQuery Method (String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx) to run the query that returns the desired data.

The `TElement` parameter type must be

- either a single type (like string) if the query returns a single value (1 row, 1 column)
- a class that has column which the same names of the columns returned by the query (if the query returns several columns) You'd have to create this class yourself, if this is the case.