# Command to tell me what's changed in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to become familiar with Magento and I want to know what tables get effected when I perform certain actions, like: creating a category, adding a product and adding shopping cart and catalog rules, etc.

Just wondering, is there a MySQL command that can tell my what tables have been effected? Something like: SELCT affected tables FROM db WHERE last updated > date.

Comment: Not entirelly right. You can use the tables on the information schema to check. But it will be painfull since you will have to have some kind of inspector to see what was changed

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ah, taking it literally at table .. I was considering row changes. (For information see "UPDATE_TIME" in [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html) and [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated) - note this does *not* work with InnoDB and it will show all changes, by anyone. So, I stand by my "no" in quotes.)

Answer (score 0):

When you run `UPDATE` in a MySQL console, it will tell you how many rows were modified.  I belive `INSERT` does the same.

Libraries that allow you to modify MySQL from your code will frequently return the number of rows that were affected, although that obviously depends on what library you are using.

I'm pretty sure that's the extent of what it will tell you and that there is no such feature to tell you about what ***TABLES*** were affected.  However, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` only affect one table at a time so if you can find the query in the code that is getting run, that is your best bet to find what tables are being modified.