# How to know when data was inserted into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anyway I can know when data was inserted (date and time) on the table? May be we can use information_schema?

I want to see the historical timings (at least since past week) when data was loaded into the table.

The name of the table is Mfg

Thank you!

Comment: It's not unusual to see people save an exact date when the entry is created in the same row as that entry. Obviously this won't work in your situation, but it's worth considering for the future if you can modify the table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/307488/2055998

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

Comment: If you only need to know "what's the last time the table is updated?", check PM77's link. If you need know when and what table updated, you may need a trigger or something similar.

Comment: How about looking in the log files?  Here is a good reference http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3076/how-to-read-the-sql-server-database-transaction-log/