# MySQL check if table has some records changed

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am working on an Java application which uses MySQL database as the data storage layer. There are few configuration tables in database, but each table has many thousands of records / rows. These all configuration is cached / loaded in memory in corresponding data structures / beans(JAVA POJO's) when application starts up.

Everything is fine except that every time the application starts the caching takes place and this usually takes 15-20 minutes, as the data to be cached is huge and also some columns have XML string which is parsed and then stored in beans.

So what's the big deal??

- Why should we cache when no data is changed between consecutive start-up's.?? I can have all the beans encapsulated in a common Config bean and serialize it. And load this serialized object the next time when I figure out no data is changed - and yes of course loading serialized object is far faster then database hit plus bean population.

So is there any way I can figure this out?
Of course at database level. I would query when the application starts - Was there any change in the database tables since it was last started. If yes do the same old boring caching process and store some unique identifier and serialize, Or if last identifier and current identifier are same just load the serialized object. This unique identifier will of course be persistent.

Comment: What about mysql CHECKSUM TABLE. I tried changing a column data for a row and checksum changed.

Answer (score 4):

Add an `last_updated` column of type `timestamp` to the table.

When you need to check if there are changes on the table simply execute the query:

```
select max(last_updated) from YOUR_TABLE
```

If the last_updated is after the time you created the last cache copy you can update the cache with only the elements changed since last creation of the cache with a query similar to this one:

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE where last_updated > LAST_CACHE_UPDATE
```

---

As explained in the comments is higly recomandable to add an index on the column `last_updated`. Using an index give you the possibility to retrieve the maximum value in a table of 1.000.000.000 records in 30 steps (not 1.000.000.000 as wrong mentioned in the comments).

---

Comment: is it that simple ? he still needs to check which row changed by comparing dates one by one

Comment: Yes it is "simple" if you add an index on the column last_updated and you work with indexes

Comment: That is not optimal answer to a good question. This is first and simple answer, so as mine. If he has 100 millon rows and 1 row has changed, he has to check 100 million dates to find which row changed?

Comment: No, if an index is present only log2(100.000.000) = 27 checks are performed.

Comment: In my case configuration / records may also be deleted. So the solution won't be feasible.

Comment: Same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369829/411189

Answer (score 0):

If you restart your application a lot and your cache can live in off memory data structure like redis or hazelcast, use that as cache, not the jvm memory. When update data, update both sides.

Comment: It works only if it is possible to update the records passing via redis. If the update is done directly via a sql client it is not taken in consideration

Comment: It's the purpose of caching, when one wants to update a record, update both datastore and cache !

Comment: Only if it possible to access directly the datastore, otherwise it is possible find the best way to see if the data present in the database are changed or not.