# How to get the exact date and time when mysql database table last updated?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I am new in web development and I am suffering from a problem to get date and time when mysql database table last updated because I have to show it on my web page. I am getting the last updated date correctly but not correct time please help me.

```
 <?php

    $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM MydatabaseName LIKE 'TableName'";
    $tableStatus = mysql_query($sql);

while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($tableStatus)) {
          $updatetime = $array['Update_time'];

          $datetime = new DateTime($updatetime);
          echo $updatetime ;
     }

 ?>
```

Comment: do you have different columns for date and time in your table ?

Comment: @Priyanshu - No , I am not storing date and time in different column. I am looking for some system define method for it , which can return the last updated date and time.

Answer (score 1):

If this could help you

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

[How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

Comment: Hi Ashish - Can you please convert the above answer in reference of php in my case I am using your code as -    <?php
       
       
$sql ="SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB Name'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table Name";

$tableStatus = mysql_query($sql);

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tableStatus))
{
  $fetch[]= $row;
echo $fetch;
} ?>    but getting empty array...

Answer (score 0):

since you have tagged a question in mysql.

Did you try this?
see if this is helpful.

```
select columns from table order by date_time column desc limit 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively recent version of MySQL, you can query information_schema.tables

```
 select substr(update_time,1,10) as date_updated,
        substr(update_time,12) as time_updated 
 from information_schema.tables
 where 
 table_schema = 'name_of_your_database' and 
 table_name = 'your_table_name';
```

Note that [this may not work for user-defined tables if your MySQL engine is InnoDB](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14374). It works as advertised on a MyISAM installation.