# How can I tell when a mySQLi table was last updated?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've seen the mySQL example here:[How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

But it's not working in mySQLi. I have this function to return the last time a specific table was updated (I am connected via another function that produces $conn), but it's not working. I want to run the function and return a date and time text. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
function getDatabaseUpdateTimes($conn,$databaseName,$tableName){
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$databaseName);
    $query = "SELECT UPDATE_TIME 
        FROM   information_schema.tables
        WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = '$databaseName'
          AND  TABLE_NAME = '$tableName'";
    $updateTime=mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
    return $updateTime;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: This only works for MyISAM engine. I prefer to use triggers!!

Comment: @ManManam suggested alternative?

Comment: @splash58 not sure the link is helping me much... any explanation why you linked it?

Comment: this is incorrect `$updateTime=mysqli_query($conn, $query);` should be as: `$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query); $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $updateTime = $row['UPDATE_TIME'];`

Comment: THANKS @splash58 that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @splash58 for the fix.

Final code:

```
function getTableUpdateTimes($conn,$databaseName,$tableName){
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$databaseName);
    $query = "SELECT UPDATE_TIME 
        FROM   information_schema.tables
        WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = '$databaseName'
          AND  TABLE_NAME = '$tableName'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $updateTime = $row['UPDATE_TIME'];
    return $updateTime;
}
```