# Is there a way to find when was a specific table last updated in database using Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

people! :D

I have an html table with all my records from a database table and I want to specify on the bottom when was the table last updated (from creating, updating or deleting a record in the database table).

Is there a built-in way in Laravel to do exactly that? Many thanks!

Looking forward for your responses. Cheers!

Comment: Store it in another table along with type of transaction in same transaction.

Comment: No such built-in feature but you can query the information_schema of your databse to find out.

Comment: Kindly refer [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated) Run the query using `DB::select()`

Answer (score 0):

You  can query for the most recently updated record and use that as reference:

```
return DB::table('some_table')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Laravel model observers - I guess this can help you get your task done.

Check the following links.

1. [Laravel Model Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers)
2. [Bosnadev – Code Factory - Laravel: Model Observers](https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/28/laravel-model-observers/)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Get Model's last updated record.

```
$last_updated_record=ModelName::select('updated_at')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Or using DB Query

```
$last_updated_record= DB::table('table_name')->select('updated_at')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
```