# print on web page date and time of last MySQL DB update

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

From what I'm gathering '`information_schema.tables`' seems the way to go...

I'm wondering if I can approach this method from the php side; instead of going into mySQL workbench/client.

I'm trying the below; but getting an empty array. Is this possible? I will later simply display a '`Last Updated DD MM YYYY`' in a `.html` page. *It seems like this should be possible from my `.php` file?*

It is a dynamic mySQL DB from a windows IIS server.. I have not made any modifications on the mySQL side at this point; only the below attempt. Seems like it should be a easy common task.

```
 <?php 
    $sql ="SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB Name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table Name"; 
    $tableStatus = mysql_query($sql); 
     while ( 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tableStatus)) { $fetch[]= $row; echo $fetch;
 } ?>
```

Comment: When you execute this same query directly in MySQL, does it show the data you expect?

Comment: use `SELECT MAX(UPDATE_TIME ) as MAX_UPDATE_TIME  from ...`  for the most recent date from that table.  PS `information_schema` is part of MySQL's structure. `it is a dynamic mySQL DB from a windows IIS server` its not dependent on server.  Dont tell anyone I use it all the time to dynamically get the column names for tables, for security reasons ... :-)  ie. key sanitization.

Comment: Are you using literally `'DB NAME'` and `'Table Name'` in your query? I doubt your database and table have those names. Those are just examples. You should substitute with *your* actual database and table names.

Comment: Also, if you connect as a MySQL user who does not have privilege to read that database or table, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA will appear to be missing those entries. You will still be able to query for them, but the rows will not be visible to your user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated